# Hahn-Banach: Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.
*(More generally locally convex spaces)*

Regard a closed subspace $U\subseteq X$.

Does every bounded operator extend:
$$T\in\mathcal{B}(U,Y)\implies T_E\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$$

*I guess not but I couldn't come up with a counterexample..*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Say $X=L^1(\Bbb T)$, and let $$Y=U=H^1(\Bbb T)=\{f\in L^1(\Bbb T):\hat f(n)=0,n<0\}.$$So $H^1$ is just the classical Hardy space, the class of functions that extend to holomorphic functions in the unit disk.

Define $T:U\to Y$ by $Tf=f$. If $T$ extended to an operator on $X$ that would be a projection from $L^1$ onto $H^1$, and there is no such projection. (See Rudin *Functional Analysis*: An averaging argument shows that if there is a bounded projection then the "obvious" projection would work, but it's not bounded.)

Come to think of it, we get a similar example if $X$ is any Banach space and $U$ is a non-complemented subspace; the above is the only non-complemented subspace I happen to know. (Ok, there's also $H^\infty\subset L^\infty$.)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was exactly hoping for a construction on a non-complemented subspace. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to ask: Why does it necessarily have to extend to a *projection*?

Comment: ??? The extension would be $T:L^1\to H^1$, with $Tf=f$ for every $f\in H^1$. That's the _definition_ of "$T$ is a projection from $L^1$ onto $H^1$".

Comment: So you mean projection simply in the sense of a surjection acting as identity on the range but nothing else about its *kernel*?

Comment: Ok I had a look in Rudin and I understand now: It clearly becomes $P^2=P$.

Comment: The original extension $T$ also satisfies $T^2=T$. That's the same as saying that $Tf=f$ for every $f\in H^1$. Now that averaging argument gives a translation-invariant $P$.